# How to view single Tiff image having multiple images

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a tiff image and I converted to png image I want to return as image or array of bytes. For example one tiff image have 3 image I want to return at a time  3 image path. Below I have given my code.

---

```
                string[] pngPaths = null;
                byte[] filedata3 = null;

                // Get an FileStream for reading the TIFF image
                using (FileStream tifFs = new FileStream(
                    dirs[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    // get a TiffBitmapDecoder
                    TiffBitmapDecoder tifDecoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(tifFs
                        , BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat
                        , BitmapCacheOption.Default);

                    // Initialize PNG image location array
                    pngPaths = new string[tifDecoder.Frames.Count];

                    // Save each page in the TIFF image
                    for (int i = 0; i < tifDecoder.Frames.Count; i++)
                    {
                        // Get a PngBitmapEncoder
                        PngBitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                        pngEncoder.Frames.Add(tifDecoder.Frames[i]);

                        // Construct a PNG image location
                        pngPath = string.Format("{0}_{1}{2}",dirs[0].Substring(0, dirs[0].LastIndexOf(".")), i.ToString(), ".png");

                    ContentType = MimeMappingWrapper.GetMimeMapping(pngPath);

                    pngPaths[i] = pngPath;
```

Comment: return File(filedata , contentType); iam returning like that but i need to return more than one image .can any one help on this how return more than one images..

Comment: return a collection if you have more than one to return

Comment: filedata =  ReadImage(pngPath); using this method i am converting .png iamge into bytes .but how how to retain more then one byte in a file data variable